# Can't create extension orafce in Postgresql

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, centos-7, postgresql, oracle-10g, psql

my os is redhat 7.3 and I am trying to install orafce to postgresql with psql version 9.2 and server version 9.6. Firstly, i try to install via the script orafce downloaded on github but after reading some topics about extension in postgresql, i understood that the installation only requires to run

> CREATE EXTENSION orafce;

in psql because the file in .sql is already present in extension directory of postgresql. But my problem is, when i run this commands it said

> ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/orafce: No such file or directory".

When i run the command

> SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions;

to find which version of orafce is compatible with my postgresql version it said version "3.1". So i run the command

> CREATE EXTENSION orafce--3.1;

in my database with a superuser and this time it doesn't give any errors. But when i check the extension list in my database as the same user with

> \dx

I don't see orafce and I can't use the orafce functions in my pgplsql code.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are seeing is because orafce is not installed correctly, Postgres is expecting to find a shared library orafce.so in its $(libdir) when you try to CREATE the extension.

In the unpacked orafce source dir is a file INSTALL.orafce which shows the steps needed to install it. Once installed

> CREATE EXTENSION orafce;

should work correctly.